# Is there anyway to change Totem Video Player keybindings?

Tags: configuration, video-player, shortcut-keys, totem

I want to change `Go Backward` and `Go Forward` keys.
is there any way to do this?

Totem default keybindings:

[image: totem video player shortcuts panel]